# VBScript to export the Groups an Active Directory user is member of?

Tags: active-directory

Is there some way, using a VBScript, that I can export all the groups an active directory user is a member of into a text file?

Additionally, is there a way of doing this for multiple users from the one script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will [**this**](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/usersgroups/groups/#RetrieveADGroups.htm) do what you want ? It should be fairly straightforward to modify it for multiple users.